# Error at OID for old SNMP Hardware

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

After fixing some bad config lines in old MIB's, I'm finally getting somewhere trying to walk an old hardware device.  However, an error is still occuring on this particular OID which I can't understand.  I would greatly apprecaite any clues:

Here is the -DALL output from walking just that particular OID:

[Here is the entire output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mattbodman/a507bcfa7e8945e91758684d348fe56f/raw/390918a99d7f9dc05d57a0058d2f53515ecf7283/output.txt)

Answer (score 0):

The OID is this one:

.1.3.6.1.2.1.11.32

```
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpProxyDrops
snmpProxyDrops OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM       SNMPv2-MIB
  SYNTAX        Counter32
  MAX-ACCESS    read-only
  STATUS        current
  DESCRIPTION   "The total number of Confirmed Class PDUs
            (such as GetRequest-PDUs, GetNextRequest-PDUs,
            GetBulkRequest-PDUs, SetRequest-PDUs, and
            InformRequest-PDUs) delivered to the SNMP entity which
            were silently dropped because the transmission of
            the (possibly translated) message to a proxy target
            failed in a manner (other than a time-out) such that
            no Response Class PDU (such as a Response-PDU) could
            be returned."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) snmp(11) 32 }
```

Most of the debug output seems to be indexing and parsing your MIBs (I counted 336 of them). At the end, the device returns "0" as the answer to the poll:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.11.32.0 = Counter32: 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for posting too much of the log file. Actually, I'm not sure what to do with the info you've suggested. Any more clues?

Comment: What kind of clues are you looking for? Or, could you elaborate a bit on the error you're seeing? What I was trying to say is that I didn't really see an error - you polled an OID and the device sent you an answer for it.

Comment: Oh I see.  Actually immediately after that OID response, `Error in packet. Reason: (genError) A general failure occured`

Comment: I incorrectly assumed the error would also be in the -DALL output, perhaps with more useful info.

Comment: OK, thanks. And, it actually was, just a little bit before the answer. So, I'd suggest to take a look at the device you were polling, if possible. In the debug there were two identical polls. Device returned "Error in Packet" for the first poll, and then responded properly to the second, identical poll.

First poll ID:
`sess_process_packet: sending message id#1746859277 reqid#800284050 len 43`

Answer from device:
`snmp_synch: Response (ReqID: 800284050 - Cmd 162)
Error in packet.
Reason: (genError) A general failure occured`

Comment: Thank you. When you say "look at the device" do you mean that it may be responding incorrectly or have some kind of internal error? If that's the case I may be out of luck because there is no newer firmware available for it. I actually have two of these boxes and they both do the same thing, unfortunately.

Comment: Second poll ID:
`sess_process_packet: sending message id#1746859278 reqid#800284051 len 43`

Second answer:
`snmp_synch: Response (ReqID: 800284051 - Cmd 162)
.1.3.6.1.2.1.11.32.0 = Counter32: 0`

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to formatting... And, yes, if you can take a look at the logs or something like that. IMO this indicates that the SNMP agent on the device was having some issues since it returned an error, and then promptly responded properly to the identical poll (you can see that the length is the same in both cases: 43)).

Comment: Is there a way I can omit the OID so that the tree can continue to be traversed? I'm very eager to see what remaining info I can get from the agent

Comment: I think there are ways you can get the info with various degrees of ease. Take a look at this thread as a direction. [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/net-snmp-coders/thread/CA%2BXNQ%3DgJuhpQH_0c1pfS_%2B%3DmOqxxyqBz5NvUi_8FLPjSWDBu3w%40mail.gmail.com/#msg36359259)

Comment: Thank you that has given me some ideas